# Why can't I add the value from my second EditText field into the database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I considered myself as someone new to the android development world. Recently while I was playing around with the SQLite database, I encountered a peculiar problem. I can view everything when run. But when I tried adding things by clicking the add button, the system just shut down. Here is my code. Please help if you know. Much appreciated.

Thanks everyone for your help. The initial question was solved But I am still puzzled with my code as I still cannot find the source of my error. Why is the database only returning me the value from the first EditText but not from the second EditText field? Thanks once again.

sqlhelper

```
package com.example.sgdriverdiary;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

// A helper class to manage database creation and version management. 
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "record";
    public static final String COL_LITRE = "rLitre";
    public static final String COL_DATE = "rDate";
    public static final String COL_MILE = "rMile";
    private static final String STRING_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_DATE+" DATE, "+COL_MILE+" TEXT, "+COL_LITRE+" TEXT);"; 
    public MySQLiteHelper(Context ontext){
        super(ontext, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(STRING_CREATE);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(3);
        cv.put(COL_LITRE, "6");
        cv.put(COL_MILE, "500");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        cv.put(COL_DATE,  dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

res/layout/record

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sgdriverdiary.Record$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mile"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/litre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mile"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/litre"
        android:layout_below="@+id/litre"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Add New Record" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

record.java

```
package com.example.sgdriverdiary;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Record extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    EditText Text1;
    EditText Text2;
    Button Add;
    ListView List;

    MySQLiteHelper mHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    Cursor mCursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_record);
        Text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mile);
        Text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.litre);
        Add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        Add.setOnClickListener(this);
        List = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        List.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    }
    public void onResumer(){
        super.onResume();
        mDb = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = new String[] {"_id", MySQLiteHelper.COL_DATE, MySQLiteHelper.COL_MILE, MySQLiteHelper.COL_LITRE};
        mCursor = mDb.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String[] headers = new String[] {MySQLiteHelper.COL_DATE, MySQLiteHelper.COL_MILE, MySQLiteHelper.COL_LITRE};
        mAdapter = new  SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,mCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
        List.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mDb.close();
        mCursor.close();
    }


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String rowId = mCursor.getString(0);
        mDb.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, "_id = ?", new String[]{rowId});
        mCursor.requery();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(3);
        cv.put(MySQLiteHelper.COL_MILE, Text1.getText().toString());
        cv.put(MySQLiteHelper.COL_LITRE, Text2.getText().toString());
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        cv.put(MySQLiteHelper.COL_DATE, dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        mDb.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null,cv);
        mCursor.requery();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Text1.setText(null);
        Text2.setText(null);

    }

}
```

logcart error

```
06-15 07:34:50.190: W/dalvikvm(3486): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at com.example.sgdriverdiary.Record.onClick(Record.java:75)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-15 07:34:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(3486):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is on the line 75 in Record.class?

Comment: mDb.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null,cv);

Comment: seems your `mDb` is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is caused because of `mDb` value which is null, you have just initialized it in your `onResumer` method. I think you made a typo error in name of this method so replace

```
public void onResumer(){
```

with

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
```

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks alot. I can't laugh at my foolish mistake. Anyway one more thing. Can I enquire why the database only record the first EditText field but not both when I have two? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3669019 database will record all values already contained by `ContentValues` object, sorry I can't understand you correctly

Comment: Oh please pardon me. What I meant was, I have two editText field. One is to record mile and the second to record litre. But now with the db working thanks to your help, the db only record the mile and not the litre value which I do not understand why?

Comment: @user3669019 your codes seems OK, try inspect your database file (*.sqlite) with a SQLite file reader (like SQLite manager Firefox plugin) and see what really is stored in it.

Comment: "mAdapter = new  SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,mCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});" I was thinking if editing this line would make any difference since only the first EditText field value can be added into database.

Comment: That's why `@Override` is invented for.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename your `onResumer()` to `onResume()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Try and add some more content to your answer next time if you want to have it accepted (as, *why* this would solve the problem).

Comment: @DonRoby The accepted answer is identical, although it has a bit more description.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct.  Actually, the question should be closed if the problem is a simple typo like this.